# Batch file to write "Uninstalling" and "Done" on the same line with a wmic uninstall

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I would like to uninstall a program via bathc using the wmic method. I would like a message saying "uninstalling..." and then "done" right after, without going to the next line. Below is the code I'm trying, but it doesn't work:

```
set /p a=Uninstalling XXXXX...........<nul
wmic product where name="XXXXXXX" call uninstall >null<nul
set /p a=Done<nul
echo.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Define "not working" - the set commands work for me with another command in the middle (not a wmic command though).  Perhaps the wmic command is writing something to the screen?

Comment: Thank you for posting the code you are trying. Please edit the post to include how you want the result to appear.

Comment: In your `wmic` line, instead of `>null<nul` try `>NUL 2>NUL`.  Also, replace `set /p a=Done<NUL` with `echo Done.` and get rid of the last line.

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments. unclemeat got it below. What I wanted the end result to look like was:
"Uninstalling XXXXX...........DONE"
however, the "Uninstalling XXXXX..........." would show on the screen first, then the batch would uninstall and then "DONE" would show on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following uses a trick posted to [DosTips by Jeb](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4213). I Believe it's what you're after.

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
copy nul sub.tmp /a > nul
for /F %%a in (sub.tmp) DO set "sub=%%a"
del sub.tmp

call :echoWithoutLinefeed "Uninstalling XXXXX..........."
wmic product where name="XXXXXXX" call uninstall >null
call :echoWithoutLinefeed " Done"

:echoWithoutLinefeed
> txt.tmp (echo(%~1!sub!)
copy txt.tmp /a txt2.tmp /b > nul
type txt2.tmp
del txt.tmp txt2.tmp
exit /b
```

Comment: Bingo! That worked. Thanks! I'm not sure I understand it, but at this point it doesn't matter much. :)

Comment: hmm... it doesn't seem to be working now. It could be when I tested it, it was already uninstalled. However, if I run it on an installed application, it doesn't work.

Comment: OK. I think I got it. Instead of >null, I tried  >nul 2>&1 and it worked.